# Apache CAMEL exception

Tags: apache-camel

Getting current exception, not sure how to resolve it. Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

```
org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: org.quartz.SchedulerException: Trigger's related Job's name cannot be null
```

```
    <camel:endpoint id="pollPipilineStarUpScheduler"
        uri="quartz://timedPipilineStarUp?stateful=true&amp;cron=0+0+0+1/1+*+?+2099;job.name=startup;" />

    <camel:route>
        <camel:from ref="pollPipilineStarUpScheduler" />
        <camel:bean ref="executionManager" method="startPipeline" />
    </camel:route>

</camel:camelContext>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition worked for Camel 2.12.2 (which version do you use?), however

- I changed your cron expression to `0/5+*+*+*+*+?+*`, because I didn't want to wait so long for the first job execution... More information about Quartz's cron expression can be found [here](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/tutorials/crontrigger).
- Options should not be separated by `;` but by `&`. In XML `&` becomes `&amp;`. In your URI the `&amp` was lost and it should therefore be `quartz://timedPipilineStarUp?stateful=true&amp;cron=0+0+0+1/1+*+?+2099&amp;job.name=startup;`. However, I don't understand that your URI with `;` worked for me...
- Instead of setting the `job.name` option, you could have been using the following format `quartz://groupName/timerName?cron=expression`.